# Excluding 'duplicates' in ls/find

Tags: file, find, ls

I am using a program which outputs a *lot* of output files in the format:

```
run_1_0001.blah
run_1_0002.blah
run_2_0001.blah
run_3_param_2_0001.blah
run_3_param_2_0002.blah
```

Each run produces drops several thousand of these files into the same directory.  The head of the filename is arbitrary and may contain numbers.  The only consistently predictable part is that the filename ends with a 4-digit number and an extension. What I'd like is to write an alias which excludes these pseudo-duplicates and produces a single line of output for each collection of files.  In the rubbish example I've given, the output would be:

```
run_1_.blah
run_2_.blah
run_3_param_2_.blah
```

Apologies if this is easy.  I did have a look around but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Its hard to say by looking at your example. If you have a source cord please provide that.

Comment: I've found a partial solution combining ls with sed and uniq.  If extension is '.blah', one can do:

ls *.blah | sed 's|[0-9]*\.blah|.blah|' | uniq

ls finds all the blah files, sed removes the trailing file numbers, and uniq excludes any of the resulting duplicates.

However, this doesn't work with ls -la, and so its not possible to show any file information.

If anyone has a better way, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it is only the numbers that differ between the duplicates, you could delete them and pass the resulting output to `uniq`, e.g.

Create test files:

```
touch some_filename_0001.blah some_filename_0002.blah some_otherfilename_0001.blah
```

Delete numbers and pass to `uniq`:

```
ls | tr -d '[0-9]' | uniq
```

Output:

```
some_filename_.blah
some_otherfilename_.blah
```

#### Edit

Based on your updated test data and the fact that you want to use `ls -la`, I suggest using `awk` to parse the data. In my version of `ls` the filename is the 9th element in `ls -la` output, so something like this should work:

```
ls -la | awk '{ sub("[0-9]{4}", "", $9) } !h[$9]++'
```

This removes a sequence of four integers from the filename column and only prints it if it has not been seen before.

Caveats: This assumes that file names do not contain spaces. Also, "runs" and "parameters" should not consist of 4 or more integers, if that is the case you need to use a more advanced regular expression to anchor the substitution.

Comment: Thanks for this, Thor.  However, one additional complication is that the filenames may contain other numbers which DO distinguish between different sets of output files like: run1_0001.blah, run2_0001.blah

I commented something I found above, which is similar to this approach but using sed instead.  Thanks though :)

Comment: @JoeTodd: please provide more representative test data and expected output.